# JQuery UI styling on DataTables

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

I have a customised JQ UI theme, using jquery-ui-1.11.4 and DataTables-1.10.9.

My table is created with :

```
    $('#tblRemittanceList').dataTable({
          "autoWidth":false
        , "info":false
        , "JQueryUI":true
        , "ordering":true
        , "paging":false
        , "scrollY":"500px"
        , "scrollCollapse":true
    });
```

I could do with some advice on how stripe (as both the odd/even are the same colour), and also how to compact rows, etc.  Thanks.

Comment: there's [example](http://datatables.net/examples/styling/jqueryUI.html) that has stripes. Stripes configuration is [here](http://datatables.net/examples/styling/stripe.html) and compacting is [here](http://datatables.net/examples/styling/compact.html).

Comment: also note that `JQueryUI` option is deprecated in 1.10 and will be removed in 1.11 - [docs](http://datatables.net/examples/styling/jqueryUI.html)

Comment: Thanks.  I'd added stripe before, but it didn't work.  It's working fine now, along with the compact, cell-border.  I'll accept this later as the correct answer later.  In terms of the  JQueryUI being deprecated in 1.11, I assume it will still support the UI styling though?

Comment: Yes it will, you will need just to reference `dataTables.jqueryui.min.css` and your theme only. No `JqueryUI` option will be required.